# Vue - load new dataset when scrollTop reach a predefined value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've created this methods inside my Vue app

```js
previousPage( colType ) {
    // Torno alla pagina precedente 
    switch( colType ){
        case 'suppliers':
            if( this.suppliersCurrentIndex > 0 ){
                this.suppliersCurrentIndex--
                this.currentSuppliersList = this.store.suppliers[this.suppliersCurrentIndex]
            }
            break;
        case 'clients':
            console.log('prevPage clients', this.currentClientsList, this.clientsCurrentIndex)
            if( this.clientsCurrentIndex > 0 ){
                this.clientsCurrentIndex--
                this.currentClientsList = this.store.clients[this.clientsCurrentIndex]
            }
            break;
    }
},
nextPage( colType ) {
    // Vado alla pagina successiva
    switch( colType ){
        case 'suppliers':
            let suppliersLength = this.store.suppliers.length     
            if( this.suppliersCurrentIndex < suppliersLength ){
                this.suppliersCurrentIndex++
                this.currentSuppliersList = this.store.suppliers[this.suppliersCurrentIndex]
            }
            break;
        case 'clients':
            console.log('nextPage clients', this.currentClientsList, this.clientsCurrentIndex)
            let clientsLength = this.store.clients.length
            if( this.clientsCurrentIndex < clientsLength ){
                this.clientsCurrentIndex++
                this.currentClientsList = this.store.clients[this.clientsCurrentIndex]
            }
            break;
    }
},
scrollPagination( colType ) {
    const maxScroll = 3336 
    switch( colType ){
        case 'suppliers':
            console.log('scrollPagination invoked')
            if( this.$refs.suppliersCol.scrollTop === maxScroll ){
                this.nextPage('suppliers')
                this.$refs.suppliersCol.scrollTop = 0
            }
            break;
        case 'clients':
            if( this.$refs.clientsCol.scrollTop === maxScroll ){
                this.nextPage('clients')
                this.$refs.clientsCol.scrollTop = 0
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

I've used the `@scroll` listener on a column I have in my template that have a fixed height. Basically I want to call internally the next page method when the `scrollTop` value reach the maximum possible and scroll back the column to the top so the user will see the new loaded results. I've noticed that the method is called but I'm unable to reach the desired result, and the nextPage method will be never fired. Is there any issue in my code?

Thank you for the help.

**UPDATE**

I've noticed that internally the nextPage methid is called, but I don't know why, it will only be fired three times but I have an array that will have a length of 40. for suppliers and 1000 for clients. any help?